# Get widgets from other layouts

Tags: android

How do I access widgets in the java-code from a layout of another Activity? I have a TabActivity which uses two tabs each with it's own Activity class calling setContentView on it's own layout. The TabActivity do this also.

I want to be able to use findViewById(R.id.id_from_view_inside_tab_activity) in the TabActivity class.

For example. I have the TabActivity Foo and another Activity called Bar. Foo have a layout called foo.xml and Bar have bar.xml. In bar.xml I declare

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background">
```

What do I need to do in Foo to be able to call findViewById(R.id.entry1) ? (Or something similiar).

Answer (score 0):

You could get an instance of the LayoutInflater and then inflate the layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater(); //this refers to Activity Foo.
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar);
EditText aText=view.findViewById(R.id.entry1);
```

Comment: I tried:

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.bar, getTabHost() );
EditText aText = (EditText)view.findViewById( R.id.entry1 );

There was no inflater.inflate(int), it required a ViewGroup and im not sure what ViewGroup to send, I tried the tabHost. When I try this aText becomes null.

Comment: You can get an instance of the LayoutInflater from the Activity. So, in the TabHost, you have a seperate Activity for each tab. Call LayoutInflater from the Activity which is present in the 1st tab. Also if you could post the code, I can probably tell you the answer.